# Will Ubuntu on USB drive run faster if I use it on a USB 3 flash drive?

Tags: usb

I installed Ubuntu on a 32 GB USB 2 flash drive. Upgraded it and installed various new applications on it. I ran fine in the beginning, but after a few days it runs terribly slow. I can't even watch a YouTube video without lag.

My question is will things be faster if I use a USB 3 flash drive?

Comment: "It's slow" could have many possible causes, and running a full install of Ubuntu from USB2 is expected to be slow. If your hardware supports USB3, and if the bottleneck is really USB2 throughput (rather than RAM or CPU or a slow network connection), then yes USB3 is very likely to be faster. Do the checking first so you're not disappointed.